# Prevent SSMS changing tab to space when copying text from Result Tab

Tags: ssms

SSMS 2016 changing tabs to spaces when copying from Result Tab (does not matter ctrl+c or drag&drop). 
For example if execute this code

```
SELECT 'a' + CHAR(9) + 'b'
```

then copy text from result tab and paste in any editor it will be space instead tab between 'a' and 'b' characters.

How to prevent this behaviour?

P.S.: Saving result to CSV working properly and saving tab (code 9). Error caused only on copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Options and check `Retain CR/LF on copy or save`.

[image]

Comment: I've checked but no result. Still space instead tab.

Comment: Close existing tab and open new one.

Comment: That's a completely unintuitive option if the goal is retaining tabs!!  (Not your fault, of course...)

Comment: Or use SSMS and Output to Text?